# Android, listing rssi values for 5 strongest wifi networks

Tags: android, android-wifi, rssi

I am trying to make a simple app that tells me the rssi values of the 5 strongest wifi networks. I don't need to connect to any of the networks, just want to know the rssi's. At the moment I'm using the following bit of code:

```
wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int info = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
textStatus.setText("WiFi Rssi: " + info);
```

However, this only displays the rssi value of the network I am connected to.

Is there a way of getting this information for other networks?

Answer (score 5):

I think I got it:

```
ScanResult result0 = wifi.getScanResults().get(0);
String ssid0 = result0.SSID;
int rssi0 = result0.level;
String rssiString0 = String.valueOf(rssi0);
textStatus.append("\n" + ssid0 + "   " + rssiString0);
```

then get(1), get(2) and so on for however many you like

Comment: The level property is the RSSI, which, according to the documentation, is measured in dBm. ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#level))